# best way to measure internet traffic over different networks

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I am developing a application in Blackberry SDK 5.0.0 end from my research the only class that deals with internet traffic is `RadioInfo` with the methods `RadioInfo.getNumberOfPacketsReceived()/Sent()`, but this methods retrieve the total traffic over all the networks, counting both mobile data and WiFi data. Is there a way to determine which network is used when the device connects to internet?

Comment: Didn't you already asked the question?

Comment: Yes but I didn't formulate the question well and the answer that I got explains how to determine which network is on and if the on networks have enough coverage to support a connection. Sorry for the redundancy but i can seem to find a solution for this one. I hope this time someone will be able to help

Comment: Did you ask on the blackberry developer forum?

Comment: I have searched the blackberry forum, this question is already asked there, but there is no answer yet.